# Retain each CSS shorthand property of an element inside a variable with jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example I have a border radius CSS property given to an element, let's say:

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

and the CSS

```
.element{border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;}
```

What I wan't to achieve are for variables, each one containing one of those CSS border-radius values

Comment: You can extract the value of "border-radius" from the element and then separate the string yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to pull the `borderTopLeftRadius`, `borderTopRightRadius`, `borderBottomLeftRadius` and `borderBottomRightRadius` values from your element. No need to split any array at all.

## Native JavaScript

Those values can be extracted by pulling the separate `border-radius` values for `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom`:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.element')[0],
    style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
```

Now you can simply exctract the values using:

```
// Top left:
style.borderTopLeftRadius;

// Top right:
style.borderTopRightRadius;

// Bottom left:
style.borderBottomLeftRadius;

//Bottom right:
style.borderBottomRightRadius;
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RcRF2/).

```
console.log({
    topLeft: style.borderTopLeftRadius,
    topRight: style.borderTopRightRadius,
    bottomLeft: style.borderBottomLeftRadius,
    bottomRight: style.borderBottomRightRadius
});

> {topLeft: "0px", topRight: "0px", bottomLeft: "0px", bottomRight: "15px"}
```

## jQuery

Similar concept in jQuery:

```
var el = $('.element');

// Top left:
el.css('borderTopLeftRadius');

// Top right:
el.css('borderTopRightRadius');

// Bottom left:
el.css('borderBottomLeftRadius');

//Bottom right:
el.css('borderBottomRightRadius');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RcRF2/1/).

```
console.log({
    topLeft: el.css('borderTopLeftRadius'),
    topRight: el.css('borderTopRightRadius'),
    bottomLeft: el.css('borderBottomLeftRadius'),
    bottomRight: el.css('borderBottomRightRadius')
});

> {topLeft: "0px", topRight: "0px", bottomLeft: "0px", bottomRight: "15px"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use split :

```
 var arrValue = $('.element').css('border-radius').split(' ');
```

This will give you an array :

> ['0px', '0px', '15px']